# How is bias added to specific hidden layers of a Neural Network in PyBrain?

Tags: python, neural-network, pybrain

I have a Neural Network with two hidden layers. I want to add a bias unit only to the second hidden layer. How do I do that?

The code for my network is as follows:

```
nn = FeedForwardNetwork()
inLayer = LinearLayer(numFeatures)
hiddenLayer1 = LinearLayer(numFeatures+1)
hiddenLayer2 = SigmoidLayer(numFeatures+1)
outLayer = LinearLayer(1)

nn.addInputModule(inLayer)
nn.addModule(hiddenLayer1)
nn.addModule(hiddenLayer2)
nn.addOutputModule(outLayer)

in_to_hidden1 = FullConnection(inLayer, hiddenLayer1)
hidden1_to_hidden2 = FullConnection(hiddenLayer1, hiddenLayer2)
hidden2_to_out = FullConnection(hiddenLayer2, outLayer)

nn.addConnection(in_to_hidden1)
nn.addConnection(hidden1_to_hidden2)
nn.addConnection(hidden2_to_out)
nn.sortModules()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly simple task. First you have to create Bias module:

```
bias = BiasUnit()
```

Then add it to your NeuralNetwork, so:

```
nn = FeedForwadNetwork()
nn.addModule(bias)
```

Then, assuming you already added other layers you have to connect bias to hidden layer of your choice:

```
bias_to_hiden = FullConnection(bias, hiden_layer)
```

And then add it to neural network:

```
nn.addConnection(bias_to_hiden)
```

Apart from that you do everything same as before.

For the reference check code of the `buildNetwork` function from [pybrain.tools.shortcuts module](http://pybrain.org/docs/api/tools.html#pybrain.tools.shortcuts.buildNetwork). Here is some code that connects bias unit to other layers (lines 75-79):

```
if opt['bias']:
    # add bias module and connection to out module, if desired
    n.addModule(BiasUnit(name='bias'))
    if opt['outputbias']:
        n.addConnection(FullConnection(n['bias'], n['out']))
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Is there also a shortcut to add a bias unit to all the hidden layers (without making an explicit "for" loop :) )?